# How to you set a transform variable's target in a prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've made a prefab for a shell that launches into the air from the launcher, then turns off screen and heads back downwards towards where the player was when it turns. How do I set the player as its target?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use a GameObject in the scene's hierarchy as a reference in a prefab transform field.
Anyway, you can have a static reference to the player and use it to find the player's transform inside the code that needs it in the prefab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said you can't.

Prefabs live in the Assets and you  simply can't have Scene-references in the assets. (The same problem exists btw for the AnimatorController)

There are however a lot of ways for getting the references on runtime.

---

## ScriptableObject

Use a [ScriptableObject](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) for storing the reference and have an according Setter component on the regarding Transform GameObject in the Scene.

```c#
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "TransformReference", menuName = "SceneReferences/Transform", order = 1)]
public class ScriptableTransformReference : ScriptableObject 
{
    public Transform value; 
}
```

In the ProjectView (Assets) do <kbd>right-mouse-click</kbd> -> <kbd>Create</kbd> -> <kbd>SceneReferences</kbd> -> Transform to create a new instance of `ScriptableTransformReference`.

And than on your player have this setter

```c#
// By adding ExecuteInEditMode this is already executed 
// without entering PlayMode
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TransformReferenceSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference the created ScriptableObject here via the Inspector
    public ScriptableTransformReference TargetScriptableObject;

    private void Awake()
    {
        TargetScriptableObject.value = transform;
    }
}
```

Than whenever you need that reference in another component simply again make a field

```c#
// Reference this in the Inspector
public ScriptableTransformReference SourceScriptableObject;
```

and access it's `value` .. to be sure in `Start` so the setters `Awake` was already executed. This time you **can** have a reference in the prefab since the `ScriptableObject` resides in the Assets as well.

---

## Find

You can use [`Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) to get an object by name and do e.g.

```c#
var playerTransform = Find("Player").transform;
```

but I would recommend to not use this .. ever. It is performance intense and if you ever change the GameObject's name it brakes your code. It also only works for finding a GameObject which is active in thw hierarchy the moment it is executed.

---

## FindObjectOfType

However, if there is only one player anyway create a dedicated class on the player like

```c#
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {}
```

it doesn't have to do anything. Now you simply can use [`FindObjectOfType<Type>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) to get its reference which is way more efficient and reliable

```c#
var playerTransform = FindObjectOfType<Player>().transform;
```

in any other components in the Scene (e.g. after Instantiating the prefab). **But** again it also only works if the according GameObject and component are active and enabled in the hierarchy the moment this is executed.

---

## Singleton

Or (ab)use the Singleton-pattern

```c#
public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static Player Singleton;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        Singleton = this;
    }
}
```

and use

```c#
var playerTransform = Player.Singleton.transform;
```

anywhere else.

---

## Dependency Injection

You might want to get into [Zenject](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/zenject-dependency-injection-ioc-17758) or similar kinds of dependency injection. Though this is a bit more completecated to set it up, once you have it working once it is a very powerfull tool for providing references even across various scenes and context based.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Projectile Motion**

This is not a Complete answer, you just work it out by changing stuffs, that will be fun.

```
var pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _target.transform.position , _projectileSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
  rigidbody.MovePosition(pos);
```

try with `transform.LookAt(targetXZPos);` to make the tip of shell point to target.

If this code didnt give you required output you should consider
***Launch Velocity,
Launch Angle,
Distance to Target*** and make the projectile formula work out, will be little more tough but will create more originality and will give the player more interesting feel to try angles (if required), launch velocity can be constant based on different shells( which is again a good idea to sell different range shells to players).